# How is egg shaped ball different from a spherical ball, aerodynamically?

Tags: aerodynamics

I don't know whether this is the right place to ask this question or not but, how is an egg shaped ball aerodynamically different that the spherical ball? What advantages could one have over the other?

Comment: Drag coefficient - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient